# Asterisk Manager cannot set sslbindport

Tags: linux, asterisk, telephony

In configuring the asterisk manager to use SSL, you have to (theoretically) do the following:

1. Generate an ssl key (with openssl).
2. Use that ssl key to generate an ssl certificate (also with openssl).
3. Concatenate (1) and (2) together to create your asterisk cert.
4. Configure the manager to enable ssl and use the aforesaid cert.

Step 4 entails adding the following lines to the manager.conf file then reloading the manager:

```
sslenable = yes
sslbindport = <somepPort>
sslbindaddr = <someIpAddress>
sslcert = /path/to/cert
```

However, upon reloading the manager the CLI throws me the following error: "__init_manager: Invalid keyword  =  in manager.conf [general].

Why is asterisk not understanding this argument?  Does http.conf need special configuring as well?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help you if you don't tell us which version of Asterisk you are using. Check the manager.conf.sample in the source code distribution of the version of Asterisk you are using to verify the settings.

/O

Comment: 1.8.5 .  I've checked and rechecked many sample manager.conf files.